# Advanced layouts in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xaml

Having worked with both WPF and HTML5 javascript, I find myself missing the well defined panels of XAML. Containers such as Grid, StackPanel, DockPanel, WrapPanel and others make it easy to create predictable resizing behavior. Also, with MeassureOverride and ArrangeOverride it is fairly easy to create new types of panels. I would like to be able to use these concepts in a HTML5/Javascript browser environment such that I can combine them with CSS and media queries.

Does anyone know of a Javascript library that mimics these concepts?

Comment: You are asking for too much mate.

Comment: As a WPF developer, I sympathize, believe me. But trying to force HTML/CSS to act like XAML is doomed to failure; they're too fundamentally different. CSS actually has some powerful features that XAML lacks; don't miss out on the good stuff by constraining yourself to think in XAML and then translate to CSS.

Comment: When using jQueryMobile I get some of the nested layout possibilities, but it does not seam to rely on any strong algorithmic foundation. At least there is nothing advertised by its creators.

Comment: I say they should get rid of HTML/CSS completely and switch over to something XAML-like.  I can't stand HTML. I've worked with it for years, and it is just so cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Try [KENDO UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) or [SENCHA](http://www.sencha.com/products/designer/) frameworks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pay for a full on IDE solution, I would give a look at the open source [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) framework.

This framework provides a lot of the boilerplate needed to get your website up and running. It has a very good grid and layout system for elements and depending on which device it is being viewed you can show and hide things.

It also has a couple of controls based on JS for tabs, sliders, and modal dialogs.

Check it out.